How to customise too simple black and white terminal UI on macOS
I have recently switched from Windows to macOS, there I was using "git-terminal" as a command-line interface because it offers some basic color coded UI which was easy to read.
Is there any other alternative of terminal on Mac or anyway we can customise the boring black-white UI of the application.
Also, I do not want to download any random emulator which will slow down the performance of the CLI and the entire OS in general.
Any suggestions ??

The colours are not provided by the terminal but by the shell or command you are running. Look at the config in Windows for git and bash

You can switch profiles (which include default colors) in Settings, you can also define your own there.

PS: Installing another terminal emulator (e.g. iTerm2) will not slow down the performance of OS or shell.
PPS: Terminal colors are tricky.
